# Connecting Azures Mobile Services to Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013, ado.net

I have a Azure mobile service database and I would like to connect it to a visual studio 2013 using ado.net in order to perform a function like read the most records in the mobile service database.
I am new to using mobile service please if anyone can give me an approach to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: this might sound stupid but im new to do this. Does it make a difference if the mobile service database is online and not the traditional mssql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn434069.aspx

or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn263175.aspx

or just google the title of your question.